# Displaying Album Info via JSON Facebook Graph API

Tags: json, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I've been looking through the different threads on the Facebook Graph API and displaying the results via JSON. The examples are great but I only want to output the info for a particular album not loop through various results.

Here is a link to the Coca-Cola Wall Photos album. https://graph.facebook.com/99394368305

What I would like to do is display the Name of the Album and the Link.

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

You can choose only the fields you want by specifying the `fields` query parameter:

https://graph.facebook.com/99394368305/?fields=name,link

From http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/#reading:

> **Selection**
>
> By default, most object properties are returned when you make a query. You can choose the fields (or connections) you want returned with the "fields" query parameter. For example, this URL will only return the id, name, and picture of Ben: https://graph.facebook.com/bgolub?fields=id,name,picture
>
> You can also request multiple objects in a single query using the "ids" query parameter. For example, the URL https://graph.facebook.com?ids=arjun,vernal returns both profiles in the same response.

Comment: +1, as long as the user/dev knows the id of the album AND it's public then the `fields` parameter is enough.